# Nginx to apache reverse proxy, instruct use of unix sockets

Tags: nginx, unix, reverse-proxy, socket

My Nginx reverse proxy works on the same machine as the webserver(apache) as follows

> ```
> server {  server_name site.net;
>     location / {
>         proxy_pass http://localhost:82;
>         proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
>         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Now instead of using TCP connections to the backend apache, how can I tune it to use unix sockets?

**Edit:**
Can someone help with the full flow, instructing apache to listen on unix sockets too

Comment: AFAIK Apache doesn't support listening on a socket ... its a web server. If performance is your reason for doing this, the difference between sockets/tcp is negligible for most web servers - as the bottleneck is whatever app is running anyway (PHP/Perl etc.)

Comment: I assume you have too many connections which stack up so you want to move proxy from tcp stack to socket. I would suggest you to try disable keepalive; also it might help to enable TCP_TW_REUSE (net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse)

Answer (score 11):

While you most likely could set Nginx to proxy redirect to a socket using `unix:/path/to/socket` syntax, Apache `Listen` directive only accepts IPv4 or IPv6, so as far as I know you can't get Apache to listen on an unix socket.

Comment: It would be trivial to script a proxy to map the unix socket to a network socket - but you lose any performance benefit. OTOH the lo interface doesn't have nearly the same performance constraints as a physical interface, even if it does slow start, as long as you've got big congestion windows then it should run at nearly the same speed as a unix socket.

Comment: Socket will still have edge on small requests where latency is essential.

Comment: The why route them via a proxy?

Answer (score 6):

You need to define an **upstream** like this:

```
upstream upstream_name {
        server unix:/path/to/socket fail_timeout=0;
}
```

And then set **proxy_pass** to reference that upstream by name, i.e.,

```
proxy_pass http://upstream_name
```

Comment: What about the webserver? Apache in this case.

Comment: Possible to give an answer with a full flow?

Comment: In a brief search, I couldn't find anything in the documentation that indicated that Apache is capable of listening on a unix domain socket.

Comment: There is no need to define upstream to proxy requests to a unix socket, `proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/socket:;` would do the trick as well, see http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass.